# PHP regex to extract special string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use regex to extract a certain syntax, in my case something like "10.100" or "20.111", in which 2 numbers are separated by dot(.) . So if I provide "a 10.100", it will extract 10.100 from the string. If I provide "a 10.100 20.101", it will extract 10.100 and 20.101.

Until now I have tried to use

```
preg_match('/^.*([0-9]{1,2})[^\.]([0-9]{1,4}).*$/', $message, $array);
```

but still no luck. Please provide any suggestion because I don't have strong regex knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: Please check my answer. If it does not work as expected, please add details to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
\b[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,4}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x9Ox7v/1).

**Details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `[0-9]{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `[0-9]{1,4}`  - 1 to 4 digits
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary.

If you do not care about the whole word option, just remove `\b`. Also, to match just 1 or more digits, you may use `+` instead of the limiting quantifiers. So, perhaps

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

will also work for you.

See a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/qiEhi4):

```
$re = '/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/';
$str = 'I am trying to use regex to extract a certain syntax, in my case something like "10.100" or "20.111", in which 2 numbers are separated by dot(.) . So if I provide "a 10.100", it will extract 10.100 from the string. If I provide "a 10.100 20.101", it will extract 10.100 and 20.101.';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10.100
    [1] => 20.111
    [2] => 10.100
    [3] => 10.100
    [4] => 10.100
    [5] => 20.101
    [6] => 10.100
    [7] => 20.101
)
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't use `\d`? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Well, `\d` will match non-ASCII digits if `/u` modifier is used. I understand it is not the case here, but since `\d` may change the scope of chars it can match depending on a modifier, I'd rather use a verbose way to describe the chars to match. It is common to use `[0-9]` to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks, it works. do you mind explaining on which occasion we want to use \b?

Comment: The first `\b` is a word boundary, and it requires a start of string or a char other then a letter, digit or `_` before the first digit matched with `[0-9]{1,2}`. The second `\b` requires the end of string or the character other than letter/digit/`_` after the last digit matched with `[0-9]{1,4}`. If you do not use the word boundaries, you will match `12.3456` in `09876512.3456789999`. If you plan to match `12.34` in `abc12.34xyz` you need to use `(?<![0-9])[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,4}(?![0-9])`.

Answer (score 2):

**Regex:**  `/\d+(?:\.\d+)/`

> **1.** `\d+` for matching digits one or more.
>
> **2.** `(?:\.\d+)` for matching digits followed by `.` like `.1234`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/786972)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='a 10.100 20.101';
preg_match_all('/\d+(?:\.\d+)/', $string, $array);
print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10.100
            [1] => 20.101
        )

)
```

Comment: Your regex matches 2 *or more* dot separated digit sequences. OP only asks to match 2 dot separated digit sequences. Length limits are also removed from the regex, and although nothing is said about that, OP might want to filter out strings like `2345.334567`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. Got it. what you were trying to say, for that i have changed... My post..

Comment: Now it is the same as one of my suggestions. `\d+\.\d+` is equal here (with no modifiers) to `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If i change this to `[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}` then it might got wrong or match with some other.. Lets the OP decide which answer he likes, But your answer is best among once.. I know wiktor..

Answer (score 1):

```
$decimals = "10.5 100.50 10.250";
preg_match_all('/\b[\d]{2}\.\d+\b/', $decimals, $output);
print_r($output);
```

---

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10.5
    [1] => 10.250
)
```

---

### [image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oV3FCX/1) | [Php Demo](https://ideone.com/iNoH2o)